# Rolling Mean with filter condition per row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, rolling-computation

How do I compute the rolling mean only for the next values that specify a row-wise condition. More specifically, I have the following dataframe and I only want to compute the rolling mean for the values that fulfill the condition *finished_time < created_time*

```
    created_time        finished_time       target
0   2023-07-21 00:10:00 2023-07-21 00:20:00 75
1   2023-07-21 00:25:00 2023-07-21 00:41:00 73
2   2023-07-21 00:40:00 2023-07-21 01:05:00 64
3   2023-07-21 00:55:00 2023-07-21 01:00:00 45
4   2023-07-21 01:10:00 2023-07-21 01:27:00 62
5   2023-07-21 01:25:00 2023-07-21 01:42:00 49
6   2023-07-21 01:40:00 2023-07-21 02:05:00 85
7   2023-07-21 01:55:00 2023-07-21 01:59:00 60
8   2023-07-21 02:10:00 2023-07-21 02:39:00 21
9   2023-07-21 02:25:00 2023-07-21 02:28:00 77
```

You can rebuild this dataframe using the following code

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(21)

created_time = pd.to_datetime('2023-07-21 00:10:00') + pd.timedelta_range(start='0 minutes', periods=10, freq='15T')
finished_time = created_time + pd.to_timedelta(np.random.randint(1, 30, size=10), unit='minutes')
target =  np.random.randint(1,100, size=10)

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'created_time': created_time, 'finished_time': finished_time, 'target': target})
```

As a comparison, I have this chunk of code which does what I want, but is super inefficient O(n^2):

```
def custom_roll(row, df, window):
    rolling_mean = (
        df.target
        [df.finished_time < row.created_time]
        .iloc[:window]
        .mean()
    )
    return rolling_mean

df.apply(lambda row: custom_roll(row, df, window=3), axis=1)
```

Can I make this code more efficient for large dataframes?

Comment: It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as follows

```
    def efficient_roll(row, df, window):
    rolling_mean = df.target[df.finished_time < row.created_time].rolling(window).mean()
    return rolling_mean

df['rolling_mean'] = df.apply(efficient_roll, axis=1, args=(df, 3))
```

Comment: That still has O(n^2) complexity, right?